# Apache redirect special cases with/without URL Replacement

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

About the project: customers are able to book/book not subdomains for their content...
So if you book the subdomain option, you have your content appearing on sub.example.com and if you don't book this option, the content appears on example.com/sub like content appears regularly. I'm trying to achieve this with the following redirection mechanism.

1. Somebody visits sub.example.com
2. The browser shows the content of example.com/sub
3. The address bar still shows sub.example.com
4. Achieved with following .htaccess located under sub.example.com

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} / [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/sub [P]
   ```

All the links on example.com/sub or sub.example.com are absolute links, so if I click on the main logo on sub.example.com, I get redirected to example.com and the browser bar changes. If I click on an article appearing on sub.example.com, it contains an a href to example.com/article so I reach example.com/article just fine.

My questions are these:

1. Is the .htaccess okay?
2. Are there any problems because of duplicate content? example.com/sub and sub.example.com look the same from the perspective of search machines. How could I manage the duplicate content problem?
3. Is this approach clever in general? If not, how am I able to achieve my requirements?

Comment: Use of the `P` flag makes the answer to 3 a “no” almost automatically, I’d say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are they all on the same server? The P-flag is generally used when the destination is not on the same server. Otherwise, just rewrite your page (see below). The address bar stays the same, but the content will be redirected.
2. Duplicate content can be solved by adding a meta tag (canonical) to the rewritten pages
   => https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en
3. If they are on the same server: No !

Example code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Sometimes the sub.example.com points to the same IP example.com is hosted on, sometimes it's a different IP. So I just want a .htaccess one the sub.example.com not on example.com. Example.com has its own rewrite rules for its system stuff... So your RewriteRules didn't quite solve, what I intented to solve.

Comment: What did you want to solve? Is it your intension of putting up a proxy server? Nevertheless, you will need to change either the htaccess in the example.com root domain or make virtual hosts in httpd.conf, to tell the webserver to look in the subfolder. It will never look there on itself (how should he know?). I suggest you put this code in the root folder (it will only work for the sub.example.com-domain and will not touch your root domain), or make a virtual host. You can then use a code like yours to proxy to another server.